# Expression Engine Related Categories

Tags: dynamic, expressionengine, categories

I've been trying to get a sub navigation going for quite some time, and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

First things first, here is the closest example of what I'm trying to get my sub nav to do. (the TVs sub nav) http://www.bestbuy.com/site/TV-Home-Theater/Televisions/abcat0101000.c?id=abcat0101000

For example, if I have 3 category Parents (Central, Portable, and Brands), If click on "Central" I would like all of the categories associated with "Centrals & Brands" to appear, leaving out anything to do with "Portable".

Another example, if I click on "Brands" I would like to be able to shop by brand, and have only the "Central & Portable" products related to that brand.

I am currently using GWcode Categories & GWcode CatMenu, to try and get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "related categories" (as there exists no such thing in ExpressionEngine by that name)? Also, please post the relevant code you've been using which has gotten you the closest to where you want to be.

Comment: Categories can be nested, and you can display items for certain categories only.

Comment: or dynamic parameters ( http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/dynamic_parameters.html ) , maybe even in combination with ( http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dynamo )

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck by replacing the native categories with a Channel Entries + [P&T Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) approach.

1. Create a 'Categories' channel
2. Add a Playa field to it with related categories (entries) from the categories channel
3. In your product channel, add a Playa field with categories (entries) from the categories channel.

The TV subnav on the Best Buy site would be recreated by displaying the related categories (mentioned in step 2) to the current viewed category.

```
{exp:playa:children entry_id="{current_page_category_id}"}
  ...
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Your mileage may vary.